# Formatting expiry date in mm/yyyy format

Tags: android, date-format, simpledateformat

So I have this class called ManagePayment and on this method I need to update it to show the expiry date in mm/yyyy format. Can someone pls help me I tell me what should I add?

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    if (MainActivity.getInstance().getProgressDialog() != null && MainActivity.getInstance().getProgressDialog().isShowing())                   
        MainActivity.getInstance().getProgressDialog().dismiss();

            if (AppConstants.ERROR401.equalsIgnoreCase("401")) {
                 new AppConstants.logoutAccount().execute();
            } else {
                if (result != null && !result.equals("")) {
                    Log.i("elang", "elang result: " + result);
                    try {
                            JSONObject resObject = new JSONObject(result);
                            String sucess = resObject.getString("status");

                            if (sucess.equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
                                JSONObject responseObject = resObject.getJSONObject("response");
                                JSONArray jsonArray = responseObject.getJSONArray("Payments");

                                mCardNumber = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getString("MaskedAccountNumber");
                                mExpirationDate = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getString("ExpirationDate");

                                MainActivity.getInstance().getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                                MainActivity.getInstance().displayView(AppConstants.CARDSUMMARY);
                        } else
                            managePaymentForm.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        AppConstants.showMsgDialog("", e.getMessage(), MainActivity.getInstance());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's say that your `mExpirationDate` has the following format: "15 Jun 2016"

Than you would need to do something like this:

```
String strCurrentDate = "15 Jun 2016";
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");
Date newDate = format.parse(strCurrentDate);

format = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/yyyy");
String date = format.format(newDate);
```

If your date has a different format, simply adjust the second line from this code